# jquery :last selector for multiple list

Tags: javascript, jquery

I Have a navigation looking like this

```
<ul class="navigation">
    <li class="navlist">
    Navigation1
    <ul>
    <li>point1</li>
    <li>point2</li>
    ...
    </ul>
    </li>

    <li class="navlist">
    Navigation2
    <ul>
    <li>point1</li>
    <li>point2</li>
    ...
    </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
etc (4 more navigations) ..
```

Now I want to select the last  and add a class to it with jquery. Normaly I wont be a Porblem. But I have 5 Navigations like this in the code. And it's only adding the class to the last one using this selector

```
$('.navigation ul:last').addClass('last_border')
```

Comment: Do you want to add the class to the last `ul` in each `.navigation` or in each `li.navlist`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This loops over the `.navigation` elements, and selects the last `ul` in each.

```
$(".navigation").each(function(i, nav) {
    $(nav).find("ul:last").addClass("last_border");
});
```

Because the `.find("ul:last")` is performed from the context of each individual `.navigation`, the `:last` will only apply to the current `.navigation` element.

---

Or because of jQuery's implicit iteration, you could actually do this:

```
$(".navigation").find("ul:last").addClass("last_border");
```

jQuery will iterate the found `.navigation` elements, and perform `.find()` on each one individually.

Comment: I was just typing this :)  don't forget to add the addClass()....  Edit: nevermind you already did

Comment: Working for me ! thanks for the pointer with the loop. Won't forget it :)

Comment: @Johnny187: You're welcome. And FYI, I added another solution at the bottom. If you chain the `.find()` after the initial selection, jQuery does the iteration for you, which will provide the same result with less code.,

Answer (score 1):

Use [the `:last-child` selector](http://api.jquery.com/last-child-selector/),

> While `:last` matches only a single element, `:last-child` can match more than one: one for each parent.

Not [`:last`](http://api.jquery.com/last-selector/).

> Note that `:last` selects a single element by filtering the current jQuery collection and matching the last element within it.

---

So you want to select *"the last ul from the last navlist in each navigation class?"* Then there's your selector:

```
$('.navigation .navlist:last-child ul:last-child')
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/HHDHE/

Comment: Given the markup, it appears as though every `ul` is the `last-child` of its parent `li`.

Comment: @Johnny187 exactly what selector are you using? Exactly which "last" `<ul>` do you want to select?

Comment: the last ul from the last navlist in each navigation class.

Answer (score 0):

I'm taking a guess here at what you really want:

`$('.navigation > li.navlist > ul:last').addClass('last_border')`

Does that help?